# angular-slickgrid, sort icon not visible on grouping by column

Tags: javascript, angular, slickgrid

I am using angular-slickgrid in my application. Grid looks like below:

[image]

Now when I group the record by CEP Code, below is the code for grouping by CEP Code:

```
groupByCEPCode() {
this.dataViewObj.setGrouping({
  getter: 'CEPCODE',
  formatter: (g) => `CEP Code:  ${g.value} <span style='color:green'>(${g.count} item(s))</span>`,
  comparer: (a, b) => Sorters.string(a.value, b.value, SortDirectionNumber.asc),
  aggregateCollapsed: false,
  lazyTotalsCalculation: true    } as Grouping);                                                    
}
```

On grouping grid looks like below:
[image]

I want to achieve below points:

1. On grouping by any field for example CEPCode, that field will show the ascending sort icon bydefault.
   (As you can see sort icon not visible in CEP Code column on grouping by this field)
2. No sorting takes place on sorting by CEP Code(when records are grouped by CEP Code)

Note: I have enable sortable property for CEPCode field.

Answer (score 0):

The sorting icons are actually completely separated from the sort itself, there are no connections between the icons and an actual sorting. When you sort directly from a column, then the `SortService` will take care of adding necessary icons but when you call it through a grouping method (which is outside of the `SortService`), then you are responsible to add necessary sort icons.

You can add the sort icons with an array of columnId/sortAsc pair (if it's descending you set the boolean to `false`)

```
this.angularGrid.slickGrid.setSortColumns([{ columnId: 'duration', sortAsc: true }]);
```

If you call another grouping that doesn't require any sort icons, you also need to advise the grid that the icons must be removed, you do that by passing an empty array

```
this.angularGrid.slickGrid.setSortColumns([]);
```

A full example of grouping and sorting by duration ascending, the `comparer` is what defines the sort (which is again outside of the `SortService` knowledge)

```
groupByDuration() {
    this.dataviewObj.setGrouping({
      getter: 'duration',
      formatter: (g) => `Duration: ${g.value} <span style="color:green">(${g.count} items)</span>`,
      aggregators: [
        new Aggregators.Avg('percentComplete'),
        new Aggregators.Sum('cost')
      ],
      comparer: (a, b) => Sorters.numeric(a.value, b.value, SortDirectionNumber.asc),
      aggregateCollapsed: false,
      lazyTotalsCalculation: true
    } as Grouping);

    // you need to manually add the sort icon(s) in UI
    this.angularGrid.slickGrid.setSortColumns([{ columnId: 'duration', sortAsc: true }]);
  }
```

I have updated the Angular-Slickgrid [GitHub Demo](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/grouping) page to reflect this.